# What is the limit to the number of KSP installations I can have on my account?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

So, the title is pretty self explanatory, but I'll clarify just to be safe. I've recently purchased KSP and installed it on my desktop PC at home. However, I am going somewhere and I want to have access to the game on my laptop. Can I also download the game on my laptop? Will this mess up the download on my desktop? Furthermore, how many installations can I actually have between different computers?

I'd assume there is no problem with it being on my laptop and desktop since the game is intended for offline and probably never connects to the internet or sends anything to the webserver. But I want to be sure before I download on my laptop so nothing gets messed up on my acct or whatever. (I like my saves very much)

NOTE: I own the game through KSP website, not STEAM. Also, both computers in question run Windows 10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Practically Unlimited

KSP for PC/Mac/Linux is [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) Free, both from KSP store and Steam. KSP is also pretty much standalone, you can just copy it and play without installation. PS4 and Xbox One versions are of course different matter.

Note: you can launch KSP without Steam, simply by running KSP.exe.

There is one ethic/law issue. You bought one "copy" so only one should be running at a time.

This means that:

- You can simply copy&paste KSP to pendrive/laptop/PC at run it there
- You can keep multiple copies of game, eg. with mods and [vanilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software)
- You can keep old game versions. Just rename/copy KSP before updating. Useful for modded games.

Remember to only use legally downloaded copy of game. Using illegal sources is both unsafe for your computer and... illegal.

This applies to both Store and Steam versions.

Note: At first run game asks to send statistics. If you agreed your IP may be sent over Internet to Squad.

---

Your saves are located in **[KSP directory]\Saves\[Name of save]\[save name].sfs**.
**persistent.sfs** is main save, loaded from main menu, other stuff tend to be quicksaves. If you want to synchronize laptop saves with PC, simply copy what you need.

Comment: Ah thanks, thats what i wanted to know. Don't worry, not going to do anything illegal. Will only be running 1 copy at a time because obviously if I'm not on my desktop playing I'll be on my laptop or vice versa. Can't be two places at once xD.